# Go offline in Edge like in Chrome

Tags: microsoft-edge, service-worker, indexeddb, progressive-web-apps, offline-mode

I am doing a POC in PWA and service worker, i hosted to application in localhost and tested in Chrome everything seems to working fine even the indexed db is getting listed properly.

to test the offline functionality :

> in Inspector > Network Tab > Offline ( check the option )

When am in Edge i didn't see this option so tried disconnecting the network but still because it reading from localhost everything is working directly and reading from server.

To check the Indexeddb and all i installed the MS Edge DevTools preview, still am not able to see the DB and Store

Is there any way to test this in Edge

Comment: For those those trying to use offline on edge follow this: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/support-for-offline-google-docs/m-p/1355589/highlight/true#M30114

Comment: You can actually create a throttling profile to simulate offline mode; devtools → Network → 'Throttling' drop-down → 'Add...' → create a custom profile with both upload and download set to 0 kb/s → switch to this throttling profile when needed to mimic an offline situation (however, not tested specifically with service-workers)

Answer (score 2):

At present, Offline mode is not available in MS Edge.

If you want to see **index db** then you can open the **developer tools** and go to the **debugger** tab.

It looks like below.

[image]

You also not need to install developer tools additionally because by default it comes with Edge. You can directly use it.

You can try to check on your side. Let us know if you still have problem in finding the index db in Edge, We will try to provide further suggestions.